# kafka Streams session windows

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams

Hello I am working on kafka  session window with inactive time 5 mins. I want some kind of feedback when inactive time is reached and session is drooped for the key.
lets assume I have

> (A,1)

record where **'A'** is the key. now if i don't get any **'A'** key record in 5 mins the session is dropped.

I want to do some operation on end of session lets say **(value)*2** for that session. is there any way I can achieve this using Kafka Stream API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka Streams does not drop a session after the gap-time passed. Instead, if will create a new session if another record with the same key arrives after the gap-time passed and maintain both session in parallel. This allows to handle out-of-order data. It could even happen, that two session get merged if an out-of-order data falls into a gap and "connects" both sessions with each other.

Sessions are maintained for 1 day by default. You can change this via `SessionWindows#until()` method. If a session expires it will be dropped silently. There is no notification. You also need to consider config parameter `window.store.change.log.additional.retention.ms`:

> The default retention setting is Windows#maintainMs() + 1 day. You can override this setting by specifying StreamsConfig.WINDOW_STORE_CHANGE_LOG_ADDITIONAL_RETENTION_MS_CONFIG in the StreamsConfig.

Thus, you want to do react if time passed, you should look into punctuations that allow you to register regular callbacks (some kind of timer) either based on "even time progress" or wall-clock time. This allows you to react if a session is not update for a certain period of time and you think it's "completed".